# Same MySQL dump command on cli and PHP return different

Tags: php, mysql, command-line-interface

**Scenario**
PHP 5.5.9 and MySQL 14.14 installed on Ubuntu 14.

Take the following mysqldump command

```
mysqldump -h myhost -u myuser -pmypassword --lock-all-tables mydb mytable --where="foo = 3" > /mypath/mydump.sql
```

When run manually **on command line** returns `0` (as expected, as per https://serverfault.com/questions/249853/does-mysqldump-return-a-status too)

```
>mysqldump -h myhost -u myuser -pmypassword --lock-all-tables mydb mytable --where="foo = 3" > /mypath/mydump.sql
>$?
0
```

When run programmatically **through PHP**

```
$cmd = mysqldump -h myhost -u myuser -pmypassword --lock-all-tables mydb mytable --where="foo = 3" > /mypath/mydump.sql
var_dump(exec($cmd));
```

returns

```
127
```

What's the difference?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation for [PHP: exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php):

> **Return Values**
>
> The last line from the result of the command. (...)

So `exec()` does not return the return value of the command but the last line of its output, i.e. whatever the command prints to its standard output.

To get the return value you must use the `return_var` argument.

> `return_var`
>
> If the `return_var` argument is present ..., then the return status of the executed command will be written to this variable.

So you need to change your code to something along the lines of:

```
...
exec($cmd, $output, $return_var);
var_dump($return_var);
...
```

(And properly quote the string literal in the assignment to `$cmd`.)